# Algorithm to find number of ways to group balls of different colours

Tags: algorithm, math, dynamic-programming, combinatorics

I have this problem that I'm stuck at for quite some time.

> We are given n balls (edit: in a line) that we want to put into different groups. Each ball has a
> color denoted by an integer. Two groupings are considered different if there are two
> balls in the same group in one grouping but not in the other grouping.
>
> Find the number of ways to group the balls such that the number of colors represented in each group is between two integers a and b (ie. a <= number of colors <= b).
>
> Edit: The groupings are such that whenever we want to split the balls into separate groups, it must occur along the line.
> So if we want to split balls of colours `1,2,3,3,4,1,3` into groups and `a=2, b=3`, then the groupings are `1,2 | 3,3,4 | 1,3`, `1,2,3 | 3,4 | 1,3`.

I'm stuck at trying to come up with a dynamic programming solution to this. One solution I thought about was to consider what happens when we have the number of groupings for k - 1 balls and to see how many groups we can put k balls into – so we keep adding balls to existing groups until we have enough balls of different color above the min number of colors requirement to create a new group. But I realized there are a lot of ways to do this and am not sure whether this is a viable direction. Any ideas?

Comment: I think you'll need FFT for this

Comment: Some examples would help. Moreover, what are the maximum values of `n, a, b`?

Comment: Do you mean fast fourier transform – i got it when I googled FFT. I have never heard of it before but then how would it be related this since FFT seems to be more about sequence decomposition?

Comment: @Damien `n` is between 1 and 1000 while `a, b` are between 1 and `n`. Thank you for the suggestion – Just realised it's a bit abstract I'll add in some examples into the question

Comment: @user14015810 you can search up competitive programming questions on the fft topic. Here's a good blog post on that: https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/43499?f0a28=1

Comment: @AbhinavMathur I see. I think I have misinterpreted the question – but thank you for the link!

Comment: @Damien Sorry I think I misinterpreted the question that's why it sounds abstract. There is also one more restriction on the grouping of the balls where the balls are arranged in a line and the splitting of balls into groups must happen along the line (ie. if the balls have colours 1,2,3,4,1,3 then once we split 1,2 || 3,4,1,3 we cannot put the first and last ball together). I'll update the question but I'll also try again as it looks easier to solve now. Thank you.

Comment: So the balls are _not_ distinct, and each ball does _not_ have a different color?

Comment: I think the balls are still distinct but I misinterpreted it so the balls can have the same colour. Thank you I'll update it again.

Comment: If i understand the problem correctly, a solution can be `X(n) = sum_{k=a to b} X(n-k)`, with memoization to avoid performing same calculation at different times. I didn't put it as an answer, as I am quite unsure that I understand the problem correctly.

Comment: Oh okay I see I think that would work – I made one more edit to the question so the balls can have the same color and the range of k would need to be changed slightly as a result but the answer will still work for me and I think it can be posted if you want. Thank you!

Comment: What's wrong with `1 2 3 3 | 4 1 3`?

Comment: If all colours are different, then it isn't clear why the notion of colour is needed at all in this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the original version of the question, all colours were different.
Then a simple solution would have been:

```
X(n) = sum_{k=a to b} X(n-k)
```

with memoization to avoid performing same calculation at different times.

As the balls can have a different colour, from a given starting point, we have to count the number of different colours from this starting point. This can be achieved by inserting the colours in a set (or a hash-set) and checking the size of this set.

In this case, for the recursion, we can use the index of the stating point

```
 X(index) = sum _{k = ...} X(index + k)
```

when the range of `k` is controlled by the number of different colours from the index.

The final result is equal to `X(0)`.